# How to find the correct path to save model parameters using Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am a beginner in TensorFlow. I am trying to use *tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier*, but I don't know how to find the path to insert in *model_dir*.
I have tried this:

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.SKCompat(tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                       hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                       n_classes=2,
                                       model_dir=("C:\\Users\Acer\Desktop\Dataset")))
```

And I have this error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_evaluation_master': '', '_environment': 'local', 'save_summary_steps': 100, '_master': '', 'keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, 'tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
}
, '_task_id': 0, 'keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_is_chief': True, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x00000098DFD030B8>, 'tf_random_seed': None, 'save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_task_type': None}
```

Which is the correct path to create the directory?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing linux file system naming  "/My_folder" as model_dir so python looks My_folder within the current working directory (cwd) in its run time environment. On Windows file system if you provide a full paths i.e. "c:\folder1\folder2folder3" then python will be absolute path given as model_dir.

What you really need is to first create a separate directory in your windows machine which is write permission for your current user profile. Use python os module to check you can save filed from python runtime to this folder.

Once above folder is confirmed to have write permission, just use that path will full absolute name and model will be saved outside python run time directory.

Comment: I have added the full path _C:\\ ... \MyDirectory_ and I have change the directory's privileges `os.chmod("C:\\ ... \MyDirectory", stat.S_IRWXO)` , and checked using `os.access("C:\\ ... \MyDirectory", os.W_OK)` = _True_, but I get the same error